# Appium with Flutter app, a web element content description is shown null even though the element attributes show some string value

Tags: java, flutter, appium-android, appium-java

I am trying to test a Flutter application with Appium 2.0.0.beta 57, using Java 15. I created a web element like here

```
@AndroidFindBy(className = “android.widget.Button”)
// @iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSNsPredicate = “type == “XCUIElementTypeTextField””)
private WebElement **scanQRCodeBtn**;
```

The Appium Inspector is showing the following attributes

```
class—>android.widget.Button
content-desc–>scan qr code
```

The Java code is given below

```
String txt = getContentDesc(scanQRCodeBtn);
System.out.println(“scanQRCodeBtn=”+txt);
```

The last print out to the console is printing

**scanQRCodeBtn=null**

What is the important thing, I might be missing here?

Thanks for your help in advance